# AWS Athena query works in console, but fails via API/Boto3 "Queries of this type are not supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I have an Athena query that works in console but fails when I run in boto3 (msg: Queries of this type are not supported)

The sql is supported according to docs e.g. CTAS `CREATE TABLE "ave_calc_tb_xyzint_1" as`
however if I remove create table and just do the inner `select` it works

I've tried formatting, referencing the db, extra/various quotes on db and table name,  and extra parenthesis (around select) but nothing seems to work, what am i missing! hope someone has an understanding?

thanks as always
Ben

```
CREATE TABLE "ave_calc_tb_xyzint_1"
as
    SELECT
substring(created_at, 2,8) day,
AVG(sentimentscore_positive) FILTER   (WHERE emotion_happy > 0 AND emotion_happy >= emotion_angry AND emotion_happy >= emotion_surprise AND emotion_happy >= emotion_sad AND emotion_happy >= emotion_fear) ave_pos,
  AVG(sentimentscore_neutral) FILTER   (WHERE emotion_happy > 0 AND emotion_happy >= emotion_angry AND emotion_happy >= emotion_surprise AND emotion_happy >= emotion_sad AND emotion_happy >= emotion_fear)ave_neu,
  AVG(sentimentscore_negative) FILTER   (WHERE emotion_happy > 0 AND emotion_happy >= emotion_angry AND emotion_happy >= emotion_surprise AND emotion_happy >= emotion_sad AND emotion_happy >= emotion_fear) ave_neg,
  count(sentiment) FILTER   (WHERE sentiment =1 ) sent_pos_cnt,
  count(sentiment) FILTER   (WHERE sentiment =0 ) sent_neu_cnt,
  count(sentiment) FILTER   (WHERE sentiment =-1 ) sent_neg_cnt,
  count(*) tweet_count,
  AVG(sentimentscore_positive) ave_pos_all,
  AVG(sentimentscore_neutral) ave_neu_all,
  AVG(sentimentscore_negative) ave_neg_all
 
FROM "db_xyzint_1"."unique_tb_xyzint_1"
GROUP BY
substring(created_at, 2,8)
ORDER BY
substring(created_at, 2,8)
```

Comment: Have you tried successively removing elements of the query to find what 'breaks' it? And have you tried using a CTE? I'm also wondering whether the problem is that it can't figure out the format of one of the columns for creating the table because it is coming through as NULL?

Comment: The query can also fail if the destination is not empty, double check your bucket does not contain a previous result

Comment: thanks for responding - sorry i did summarise above, but yes i did .  if I remove create CTAS table and just do the inner select it works